# Blog Site RSS Web Part not shown

Tags: 2013, web-part, administration, blog, rss

In Sharepoint 2013 a Blog Site RSS Web Part is not showed until the SC Admin account(s) navigates to the landing page for the first time.

Any idea why this way? 
Or if it's possible to force it.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before site admin access the landing page, the Blog Notifications Web Part (RSS WP) has not ListId associated, but after access is automatically set and within the RSS WebPart shows the corresponding ‘Posts’ List contents.
Workaround: Set on RSS Web Part the corresponding ‘Posts’ ListId Guid

```
    try{        
            $PostsList = $oWeb.Lists[$ListName]
            if(!$PostsList){ throw ("Posts List not found with name: {0}" -f $ListName) }
            $ofile = $oWeb.GetFile($oWeb.Url + "/default.aspx")
            $wpm = $ofile.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
            $RSSWP = $wpm.WebParts | where {$_.WebBrowsableObject.ToString() -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BlogLinksWebPart"}
            if(!$RSSWP) { throw ("RSS Web Part not found. {0}" -f $SiteName) }
            $RSSWP.ListId = $PostsList.Id
            $wpm.SaveChanges($RSSWP)
            Write-Host ("<div>[Info] RSS Web Part updated with List ID value: {0}</div>" -f $PostsList.Id)
}
catch [Exception]{
       $catchError = ("Updating RSS Web Part List Id with the following error message: {0}" -f $_)
    Write-Host $catchError -ForegroundColor "Red"
}
```